# Custom tableview cell - Need to getting selected the cell even press a custom button in the cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a custom tableview.

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

var firstBtn  : UIButton!
var secondBtn : UIButton!

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    // button frame coding
    self.contentView.addSubview(firstBtn)
    self.contentView.addSubview(secondBtn)
}
```

In view controller i created tableview programatically.

```
colorTableView.frame = CGRectMake(20,50,100, 200)
colorTableView.delegate = self
colorTableView.dataSource = self
colorView.addSubview(colorTableView)
```

And the problem is when select a cell it highlight as gray color.But when i press a button in the same cell the highlight color disappears.So i cannot able to find which cell is selected.

I need to be remain selected the cell till go to next cell.

And I tried to fix it by manually give backgound color as follows but that not work as i wish.

```
Cell?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
Cell?.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Cellforindexpath

```
           func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell


            cell.contentView.addSubview(cell.firstbutton)

        cell.firstbutton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonpress:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
       }
```

Comment: You need to change the cell color in didSelect: method of UITableView delegate. When you select a cell, change it's bg color in this method.

Comment: I dont want to change the color.I need to be getting selected cell default color untill it go to another cell

Comment: You need to create a NSIndexPath variable as currentSelectedIndex and in didSelect you need to check if method parameter indexPath is different from currentSelectedIndex and do changes based on it.

Comment: If you can give me code means will useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With God Grace finally i got the solution.

First Step: Store the selected row's indexpath

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
    println("row selected")
    GetIndexOfRow = indexPath

    return GetIndexOfRow
}
```

Then in cellForAtIndexPath Method:

```
          if getIndexpathOfRow != nil {
        if indexPath ==  getIndexpathOfRow {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.85, alpha: 1)
            cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.85, alpha: 1)

        }else {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        }

    }
```

These gives a selection of row with  light gray color as default selection color of tableview cell.

```
      for view in self.view.subviews {
        for each in view.subviews {

            if each.isKindOfClass(UITableView){
                var getTableview = each as! UITableView

                for (var j = 0; j < getTableview.numberOfSections(); ++j)
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < getTableview.numberOfRowsInSection(j); ++i)
                    {

                                                                                var cells =  getTableview.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: j))

                        if cells?.textLabel?.backgroundColor  == UIColor(white: 0.85, alpha: 1.0) {
                        cells?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                        cells?.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                        }



                    }
                }


            }
        }


    }
```

The above code works as follows.When we select a row its check visible cells background cell color.If any-other cell has color means.Changed to clear color(In my case white color).So we can only see the selected cell highlight.

This is enough to the cell getting highlighted if even work outer buttons or button in the cell.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution.

Create a variable like -     `var currentSelectedIndex: NSIndexPath!`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
      if self.currentSelectedIndex != indexPath {
            let previosSelectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(self.currentSelectedIndex) as! UITableViewCell
            selectedCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            self.currentSelectedIndex = indexPath
            let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
            selectedCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        }
}
```

Comment: currentSelectedIndex where i can initialize in cellforindexpath delegare?

Comment: In the view controller where table exist. The colors i took randomly, you should use your desired color.

Comment: Thats ok. I am asking where that value stored , ex: currentselIndex =.In clear where the value updated

Comment: This give color to the cell.but when i press a button on the same cell the color disappears

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a custom function for your button, for example (use Button as sender)
2. Your button function:

   ```
   func buttonpress(sender: UIButton) {
   // get the cell and table
       var cell: UITableViewCell = sender.superview.superview as UITableViewCell
       var tableView: UITableView = cell.superview as UITableView
       let rowToSelectIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
       tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(rowToSelectIndexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
   }
   ```

Comment: error:Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewWrapperView'  to 'UITableView'

Comment: I dont know your exact layout - with .superview you are going to the parent container - check out your scene (and maybe you need multiple .superview) -> check first if the cell is fine (print out any cell value after var cell: ....)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not rely on selected index of row, you just use the tag property of button to find out the particular sender.